# System.Web.mvc.HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for EnumDropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been following this tutorial http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2010/05/21/asp-net-mvc-creating-a-dropdownlist-helper-for-enums.aspx but I run into the error "System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for EnumDropDownListFor".

Model:

```
public enum Codes
{
    IBC2012,
    IBC2009,
    IBC2006,
    FL2010,
    CBC2007
}

public class Code
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Active { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Edition { get; set; }
    public Codes Code { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression)
    {
        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        IEnumerable<TEnum> values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum)).Cast<TEnum>();

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items =
            values.Select(value => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = value.ToString(),
                Value = value.ToString(),
                Selected = value.Equals(metadata.Model)
            });

        return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(
            expression,
            items
            );
    }
```

HTML Helper:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Code.Codes)
```

Comment: Change the first parameter of your `EnumDropDownListFor` to be `this HtmlHelper htmlHelper`

Comment: Is the EnumDropDownListFor html helper is in controller? Extension methods should be in some static class as far as I know

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You forgot to bring the extension method in scope inside the view. This `EnumDropDownListFor` method is defined in some static class inside a namespace, right?

```
namespace AppName.SomeNamespace
{
    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

You need to add this namespace inside the view in which you want to use this helper:

```
@using AppName.SomeNamespace
@model MyViewModel
...
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Code.Codes)
```

And to avoid adding this using clause to all your Razor views you could also add it to the `<namespaces>` section of your `~/Views/web.config` file:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="AppName.SomeNamespace" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Answer (score 5):

As @ArhiChief hinted at in their answer, my problem was:

```
using System.Web.WebPages.Html;
```

Instead of:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

Both of which have definitions for `HtmlHelper` so if you add the wrong one, you will get this error.  Replacing it with the correct namespace will fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Change your namespace to

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
...
```

Comment: This worked for me... no idea why.   I do see that System.Web.Mvc is one of the registered namespaces in the web.config.. but why can't I add my own? None of the tutorials, videos or anything I seen mention this.  Everywhere I saw it said to create a namespace and add it to the web.config.  I did this multiple times and even thought I could use my extended methods (e.q @Html.MyMethod()) Intellisense would not pick it up.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had my extensions namespace referenced, but was missing a using statement for System.Web.Mvc.Html.

(The DropDownList methods are defined in System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem is that your `HtmlHelper` doesn't contain defination for `DropDownList` because of `HtmlHelper` defined in several namespaces: `System.Web.Mvc` and `System.Web.WebPages.Html`. The `System.Web.WebPages.Html` namespace contains `HtmlHelper.DropDownList`.

Also, don't forget to post your html helper namespace into Views Web.config, so, Razor view engine will find it.

Answer (score 1):

Pay particular attention in Darin's answer that you will be adding your namespace to the web.config in the **Views** folder. **Not** the `web.config` file in your root web folder. I didn't notice it at first, and for a while was baffled as to why it wouldn't work after adding my namespace to the root `web.config` file.

I think this also explains why it works for those who change their namespace to `System.Web.Mvc` in their HtmlExtensions class. `System.Web.Mvc` is already included in the namespaces in the `~/Views/web.config` file.

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, the correct namespace needs to be in the web.config file under the views folder. The default namespace is automatically included in the web.config file under the views folder.

If your default namespace is

```
 namespace AppName.SomeNamespace
```

The web.config file already contains the entry:

```
 <add namespace="AppName.SomeNamespace" />
```

What has not been mentioned before is when you create a new folder in your MVC project the namespace gets extended. If you created a folder called Helpers, like I did then your namespace for these methods will be:

```
 namespace AppName.SomeNamespace.Helpers
```

The extended namespace is not in the web in the web.config file under the views folder.

You have two options:

1. Change the namespace in the file with the html helper methods to the default namespace by removing the ".Helpers".
2. Add the extended namespace to the web config file

   ```
   <add namespace="AppName.SomeNamespace.Helpers">
   ```

Answer (score 0):

We use VB and were having the same issue.  The only thing that worked for us was, in the _PartialView.vbhtml page:

```
@* Import the project's root namespace *@
@Imports MyRootNamespace

@* Import the Module that contains the HTML Extension Functions *@
@Imports MyHtmlHelperExtensions

@* To use the extension, We have to call the extension function directly 
   Passing the Html (HTML Helper Object) as the first parameter. *@
MyExtensionFunctionName(Html, "Hello World")
```

For reference, our HTML Extensions file looks like this:

```
Imports System.Web.WebPages.Html    

Public Module MyHtmlHelperExtensions

    '== Example
    <Extension()>
    Public Function MyExtensionFunctionName(ByVal html As HtmlHelper, ByVal textToDisplay As String) As IHtmlString
         html.Raw(textToDisplay)
    End Function

End Module
```